# Instanciate Laravel DB object with same handle of PDO object

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo, laravel-4

I have a problem when I'm using both PDO and Laravel DB object. I work on a old PHP project with several PDO usage. I try to use Laravel gradually with DB object. But I have **many PDO transactions** in my code, and **DB Laravel uses a different postgres handle of my PDO object**.

So **Laravel DB ignores my PDO transaction**. I want to **instanciate Laravel DB object with the same database handle of my PDO object**.

Example of my problem :

```
PDO -> BEGIN transaction
PDO -> add records
LaravelDB -> Remove these records
PDO -> COMMIT transaction
Both PDO and Laravel -> Records exist. So Laravel query has no effect.
```

Do you know a way to do that ?

I use Postgresql 9.1 and Laravel 4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big thank you to RiggsFolly for this answer which almost gave me the solution.

## Define PDO object in DB Laravel

```
DB::connection()->setPdo($pdo);
```

## Get PDO object from DB Laravel (from RiggsFolly answer)

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

[Documentation Link](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html)

Comment: You should also accept this as the right answer, it will point others to the fact this is a correct solution to your specific question and you get points for it as well.

Comment: Yes, I will do it in 22 hours (SO prevents me to accepts my own answer now). Thank you again !

Answer (score 4):

I dont know of a way of telling Laravel to use a pdo object you create, but there is a way of getting hold of Laravels connection object and using that for yrou other database work/transactions

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

Not quite what you were asking I know, but it might be of use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, on the whole of my application I used an PDO object extended named DbPDO. Can I create an DbPDO instance from PDO instance ?

Comment: Thanks to your answer I find the solution. Thanks. +1